# Ranges with Dual Numbers

Tags: julia, automatic-differentiation

I am having an issue dealing with Dual numbers inside of ranges. Specifically:

```
using ForwardDiff: Dual
t = Dual.((0.0,10.0),0)
(t[1]:1/60:t[2])[end]
```

The issue seems to be that `[end]` uses `last` which then what's to compute the number of steps, so something is trying to convert to an `Integer` and fails. Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: I think hat the core of the problem is that `Dual <: Real` but `div(::Dual, ::Dual)` returns `Dual` which is against a contract for `div` on reals, which should return an integer.

Comment: Yeah, so how do you work around that?

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it like this:

```
using ForwardDiff: Dual, value
t = Dual.((0.0,10.0),0)
Base.Integer(x::Dual) = Integer(value(x))
(t[1]:1/60:t[2])[end]
```

But probably DualNumbers.jl maintainers should decide if this is an intended behavior in general. I would say yes, as `Dual` is not a subtype of `Integer`. Also it should not break anything as method `Integer(::Dual)` was not defined before so it could not be used anywhere.